# window.location.reload() only refresh the home page, Why it does not refresh the other pages specifically using angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, routes, google-chrome-devtools, refresh

When I navigate from the home page to the menu page, the menu page should refresh once automatically after the navigation, but when I used the following codes, it refreshes the home page and then navigating to the menu page, where the menu page is not refreshed automatically

1)First Method:

```
this.router.navigate([`locations/${locationId}/menu`])
      .then(() => {
        window.location.reload();
      });
```

2)Second Method:

```
this.router.navigate([`locations/${locationId}/menu`])
      .then(() => {
        location.assign(locations/locationId/menu);
      });
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what are the 2 methods here for?

Comment: Those are the two methods by which I tried to refresh the menu page after navigating from the home page.

Comment: you can  shift the reload logic to the actual component which needs to be reloaded. You can subscribe to the NavigationEnd event and then check the route you're coming

Comment: I have given the reload logic in the actual component of the menu page.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve but if you want to reload the menu page from the home page then you should do changes as following :

```
this.router.navigate([]).then(_result => {
    window.location.replace(`locations/${locationId}/menu`);
});
```

Comment: Thank you @Devang Patel